# How to remove spacing in the grid?

Tags: css, css-grid

I would like to remove the big spacing that is after "google" and "developer jr", is it possible to remove it?

I tried decreasing the padding, and using justify/align to see if any changes happened.
How to remove spacing in the grid?

here is my code below: the style is included in the CSS.
Everything is contained inside  element.

**HTML**

```html
<section id="projects">
  <div class="project-xp">
    <h3 class="project-title">Google</h3> <span class="project-title">Developer Jr</span>
    <p class="project-p">paragraph - text test.</p>
    <ul class="project-skills">
      <li>HTMl</li>
      <li>CSS</li>
      <li>JavaScript</li>
      <li>UI Design</li>
      <li>UX Design</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="project-xp">
    <h3 class="project-title">google</h3>
    <span class="project-title">Developer Jr</span>
    <p class="project-p">paragraph - text test..</p>
    <ul class="project-skills">
      <li>HTMl</li>
      <li>CSS</li>
      <li>UI Design</li>
      <li>UX Design</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </section>

  <style>
    .project-xp {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
      max-width: 1200px;
      background-color: #FDF5E8;
      padding: 30px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      justify-items: left;
      gap: 10px 20px;
      margin-bottom: 40px;
      border-radius: 4px;
    }
    
    .project-title {
      color: #31110B;
      font-size: 1.5rem;
      font-family: "fira sans", system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
      font-weight: 500;
      line-height: 1.1;
      margin: 0px;
    }
    
    .project-p {
      color: #31110B;
      font-size: 1.25rem;
      font-family: "fira sans", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      font-weight: 400;
      max-width: 35ch;
      padding: 0px;
      line-height: 1.6;
    }
    
    .project-skills {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      gap: 10px;
      max-width: 40ch;
      padding: 0px;
    }
    
   .project-skills li {
      color: #462A00;
      font-size: 1rem;
      line-height: 1.4;
      font-family: "fira sans", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      list-style: none;
      padding: 5px 15px;
      background-color: #F0D5AB;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
      border-radius: 4px;
    }
    
   
  </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Demo code**

```css
.projects{
background-color: #FDF5E8;
padding: 30px;
}

.project-xp {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
max-width: 1200px;
margin: 0 auto;
justify-items: left;
gap: 10px 20px;
margin-bottom: 40px;
border-radius: 4px;
}

.project-title {
color: #31110B;
font-size: 1.5rem;
font-family: "fira sans", system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
font-weight: 500;
line-height: 1.1;
margin: 0px;
}

.project-p {
color: #31110B;
font-size: 1.25rem;
font-family: "fira sans", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-weight: 400;
max-width: 35ch;
padding: 0px;
line-height: 1.6;
}

.project-skills {
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
gap: 10px;
max-width: 40ch;
padding: 0px;
}

.project-skills li {
color: #462A00;
font-size: 1rem;
line-height: 1.4;
font-family: "fira sans", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
list-style: none;
padding: 5px 15px;
background-color: #F0D5AB;
margin-bottom: 5px;
border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="projects">
  <h3 class="project-title">Google Developer Jr</h3>
  <div class="project-xp">
    <p class="project-p">paragraph - text test.</p>
    <ul class="project-skills">
      <li>HTMl</li>
      <li>CSS</li>
      <li>JavaScript</li>
      <li>UI Design</li>
      <li>UX Design</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```